# is there any way to get derivative path from public key and xpub?

Tags: electrum, bip32-hd-wallets

I have an xpub derived from `m/44'/0'/1'` can I get that path again from generated xpub or pubkey?  something like

```
def get_path(xpub):

   return derivative_path
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't, apart from trying various paths and re-deriving it.